Gazebo GUI not launching
I am trying to use gazebo harmonic in a Podman container through Distrobox. This worked for a little bit but now it just opens a black window and stops responding.
when running gz sim -v 4 shapes.sdf The following debug message loops:
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:343] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient..
I am just running shapes.sdf so no worlds should need to be downloaded.
I have attempted to use gz sim -s -v 4 shapes.sdf and then check it with gz service --list but the gz server is not listed even through it is running.
From what I've seen in some github issues this typically is a network issue often related to multicast.
Though through testing with ros2 multicast send/receive multicast appears to be working.
I don't know what other network setup would be needed. Since I'm using Distrobox everything should be working in the host network.
If anyone could help, I would be very grateful. This has been driving me insane.
here is a full log of gz sim -v 4 shapes.sdf in case I missed an important detail:
[Msg] Gazebo Sim GUI    v8.6.0
[Dbg] [gz.cc:166] Subscribing to [/gazebo/starting_world].
[Dbg] [gz.cc:168] Waiting for a world to be set from the GUI...
[Dbg] [Gui.cc:263] Waiting for subscribers to [/gazebo/starting_world]...
[Wrn] [Gui.cc:271] Waited for 10s for a subscriber to [/gazebo/starting_world] and got none.
Gtk-Message: 13:20:46.857: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 13:20:46.857: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[Dbg] [Application.cc:96] Initializing application.
[Dbg] [Application.cc:170] Qt using OpenGL graphics interface
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:657] Create main window
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:413:17: QML ToolButton: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:413:17: QML ToolButton: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Dbg] [PathManager.cc:68] Requesting resource paths through [/gazebo/resource_paths/get]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:413:17: QML ToolButton: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:343] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:343] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
Escalating to SIGKILL on [Gazebo Sim Server] ``` 

Runtime details:
Running on Podman with Distrobox
OS Ubuntu 24.04 
The network is the host network.
ROS2 distro: Jazzy
Gazebo version: harmonic


For those who come across this question.
The problem was the firewall. I was using firewalld. I could have just configured firewalld to work with gazebo but I ended up just switching to ufw and that solved the problem.
Edit: turns out when I wrote this I forgot to enable ufw. It should still work, you will just need to follow the ros tutorial of setting up ufw to work with ros.

it did not for me did you change anything else?

@IsraaAbdelghany You are going to want to make sure that you used systemctl to disable firewalld and enable ufw.
If that does not work and ufw is working, then try going through this doc
If that does not work disable your firewall to make sure that it is actually the problem.
